# \edtext breaks hyphenation of a word

Tags: hyphenation, reledmac

In the following example the word `hetūphalāvasāyī` doesn't get hyphenated, apparently because of `\edtext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
          \pstart XXXXX nanu ca pūrvottarakālayoḥ saṃvittī, tābhyāṃ vāsanā, tayā ca \edtext{hetu}{\Afootnote{hetū}}phalāvasāyī vikalpa iti cet tad ayuktam | sa hi vikalpo gṛhītānusandhāyako 'tadrūpasamāropako vā |
        \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any (automatic) workaround for this other than manually applying discretionaries?

Edit: Actually this is a more general problem, that commands inside a word will break the automatic hyphenation. `some\label{something}thing` is another candidate, also special characters like `[some]thing`.

Comment: The footnote node makes it impossible to consider `hetuphalāvasāyī` a run of letters for the purpose of hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but that's unfortunate. I wonder if there's some workaround to avoid that effect. `\edtext{hetu}{\Afootnote{hetū}}\hspace{0pt}phalāvasāyī` makes it possible for hyphenation to occur in the latter half of the word, but it can lead to a newline without hyphen to occur between `hetu` and `phalāvasāyī` which is also not desirable.

Answer (score 4):

As @egreg explain, and as you see yourself, splitting a word with command makes it impossible to consider as a run of letters for the purpose of hyphenation.

Hoewever, reledmac has a feature which can help you : you can manually decide which word will be added in the footnote, different to the word in the text, with the lemma command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
          \pstart XXXXX nanu ca pūrvottarakālayoḥ saṃvittī, tābhyāṃ vāsanā, tayā ca \edtext{hetuphalāvasāyī}{\lemma{hetu}\Afootnote{hetū}}
           vikalpa iti cet tad ayuktam | sa hi vikalpo gṛhītānusandhāyako 'tadrūpasamāropako vā |
        \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

The only problem I saw is in the cause of the world which is on two line but the lemma is only on one lines: the line number will be wrong. I can't see, now, any solution. Of course you can use `\linenum`, but to automatically know if a part of word is around two lines, you should use a edlabel, and so it will be impossible to make hyphen…